# CSS: how to correct position of image

Tags: css, image, position

I was on many forums, but nobody could give me answer. This site is my last chance.

I have a image viewer, based on javascript. There is certain count if columns of images (JS cound depends on php/mysql rows count). Now, in the output there are three columns of images, that are on two lines. When I have a maximum screen resolution I can open this link to see how the viewer looks:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mfbM/22/

The images are thumbnails. When I move a mouse over third thumbnail in the line, the image zooms itself. I correct position of image by css positioning, to the right or left, depending on image size. So the image to stay inside the inner size of window/screen. So it should stay in the position at the first line, at right. But what happens is that the image jumps on next line to the left instead (you would see blinking of image because there is onmouseout event to hide the image.). I ask how to stop the jump on the next line and ignoring relative position at css rules. I made the parent dive wide to be sure that the image has enough of room.

Edit:
I have these images from firebug css debuger to show you the styles:

[Image 1](http://svetobrazku.cz/upload/viewer.php?id=rgh1319790252z.jpg)

[Image 2](http://svetobrazku.cz/upload/viewer.php?id=viu1319790616v.jpg)

[Image 3](http://svetobrazku.cz/upload/viewer.php?id=bwy1319790927w.jpg)

And image 2 same link but "viu1319790616v.jpg"
And image 3 same link but "bwy1319790927w.jpg"

Comment: Hi @Joe. I'm a zero in JS debugging, but just wondering: What do you need your gallery to do? Zoom when over? If you can't find a solution for this, there are tons of galleries using the same library.

Comment: @utopicam: I did not say that it is gallery! I do not look image gallery. This is image viewer given to specific situation. Image viewer given to fast overlook of the images, without clicking on them. The click action is pre-defined for different purposes then viewing image. And I think this is more about CSS then JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using zoom property in css . u can avoid a large  piece of code.

Comment: that property is a MS IE proprietary property only, it will not work in FF or many other browsers.

Comment: you could use -moz-transform in firefox though. I just realised :P

Comment: @utopicam: zoom doesn’t work in Firefox or Opera, but it does work in Chrome (since version 2) and Safari (since version 4).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed later that in my original code I excluded the onload=setImages(); I don't remember why I did that but it seems to me, that this was the difference, that caused jsfiddle example no. 22 did not work correctly. Therefor here is new update without the onload event:
[example #24](http://jsfiddle.net/5mfbM/24/)
This one get thumnnail to its original size.

It looks like this code works correctly on jsfiddle (extend the window/frame bars to get maximum width if window/frame), but not on my computer on original code...